# Stripe Checkout for recurring donations of variable amounts

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe Checkout to allow users to set up a monthly recurring donation for an amount of their choosing. When I set up the Session, it provides the correct inputs to the Stripe form, however when I look in Subscriptions in the back end of Stripe, nothing is created, and it seems to just take a single payment. Here is my code:

```
   $checkout_values['success_url'] = $success_url;
   $checkout_values['cancel_url'] = $cancel_url;
   $checkout_values['payment_method_types'] = ['card','sepa_debit'];      
   $checkout_values['mode'] = 'subscription';
   $checkout_values['metadata']['order_id'] = $order_id;

   //Single line item for the dynamically created subscription and price info
   $line_item = [
         'price_data' => [
               'recurring' => [
                       'interval' => 'month',
                       'interval_count' => 1
                        ],
                'currency' => $order->get_currency(),
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => $item->get_name()
                ],
               'unit_amount' => $item_total
               ],
           'quantity' => 1,
          ];
               
          $checkout_values['line_items'][] = $line_item;
```

Maybe I need to create a subscription in Stripe and tie that in?  In which case why doesn't it give me an error?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to explicitly create a subscription object. If you use Stripe Checkout, a subscription will be automatically created when your customer completed the payment flow in your checkout page.

You might want to firstly check if you are viewing the right mode (either Live or Test), and then take a look at the Dashboard [Events](https://dashboard.stripe.com/events) to confirm subscription related events. You application can also listen to [webhook events](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks) to get notified.

Comment: Thanks qichuan. Turns out that this code is perfectly fine; I was doing a check further up to determine whether there was a subscription and this always returned false. Now I've fixed that it's working fine.